# Regex which allows alphanumeric character and only single "-"

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to prevent user input of the following characters into input fields

```
~!#$%^&*()+/\"'`:;{}[]|<>=–
```

Take note that the `–` is 2 consecutive `-`

I have tried `^[a-z ]+([-])[a-z ]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please post example valid and invalid strings

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/IZ1OMP/1 `^[a-z ]+-{1}[a-z ]+` perhaps? Also note this also stops [0-9] and [A-Z] and only at the beginning of a string

Answer (score 1):

Here is variation of @Rohan's/@mplungjan's answer. As the validation will be done at submit time the typing of more than one "-" will not be prevented while you are typing.

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text" pattern="^[\w\s]*-?[\w\s]*$" title="Only letters, numbers, whitespaces and one '-' are allowed">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is another JavaScript-based version, that will quietly remove any of the unwanted characters:

```js
const pattern=/^[\w\s]*-?[\w\s]*$/
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 ev.target.value=ev.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g,"").replace(/-(?=.*-)/,"")
})
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```